# Перестал работать position:sticky

Tags: html, css, position

Такая проблема, у меня перестало работать position: sticky, не знаю из-за чего, делал правки, но вроде не трогал этот участок кода. Сам сайт, где оно пока что работает: 1-min.ru. Вот сам код:

```
            <div class="comand-stuff">
            
            <span class="mobile-stuff-thank">
                <svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M15 23L13.84 21.849C9.72 17.7771 7 15.0916 7 11.7956C7 9.11008 8.936 7 11.4 7C12.792 7 14.128 7.70627 15 8.82234C15.872 7.70627 17.208 7 18.6 7C21.064 7 23 9.11008 23 11.7956C23 15.0916 20.28 17.7771 16.16 21.8578L15 23Z" fill="#8764C1"/>
                    </svg>
                    <p style="font-weight: bold;">Вы - лучшие!</p>                    
            </span>
            
            <div>
                <h4>Кети Доусон</h4>
                <p>(Университет Нового Южного Уэльса (UNSW))</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>Марк ван Оммерен</h4>
                <p>(Всемирная Организация Здравоохранения - (ВОЗ))</p>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                <h4>Нэнси Бэрон</h4>
                <p>(Институт психосоциальных услуг и обучения)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="more-stuff">
                <div>
                    <h4>Пьер Бастин  </h4>
                    <p>(Международный комитет Красного Креста)</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Джонатан Биссон</h4>
                    <p>(Университет Кардиффа)</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Дэн Чизхолм   </h4>
                    <p>(Всемирная Организация Здравоохранения - (ВОЗ))</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Нирджа Чоудхари  </h4>
                    <p>(Сангат, Индия)</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Рэйчел Коэн</h4>
                    <p>(Сommon Threads Project, США)</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Пим Куиджперс  </h4>
                    <p>(Амстердамский свободный университет)</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Джоанна Эппинг-Джордан  </h4>
                    <p>(Сиэтл, США)</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Мишель Функ   </h4>
                    <p>(Всемирная Организация Здравоохранения - (ВОЗ)</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Клаудиа Гарсия-Морено  </h4>
                    <p>(Всемирная Организация Здравоохранения - (ВОЗ)</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Стивен Холлон  </h4>
                    <p> (Университет Вандербильта)
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Сарб Джохал  </h4>
                    <p>(Университет Мэсси)</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Дейл Джонс  </h4>
                    <p>(Всемирная Организация Здравоохранения - (ВОЗ)</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Линн Джонс  </h4>
                    <p>(Гарвардская школа общественного здоровья)
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Берит Кизельбах    </h4>
                    <p>(Всемирная Организация Здравоохранения - (ВОЗ)</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Аннет Клейбоер    </h4>
                    <p>(Амстердамский свободный университет)
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Роос Корсте    </h4>
                    <p>(Амстердам, Нидерланды)
                    </p>
                </div>
    
                <div>
                    <h4>Айсиха Малик    </h4>
                    <p>(Оксфордский университет)
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Анита Марини    </h4>
                    <p>(Римини, Италия)
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Лаура Мюррей    </h4>
                    <p>(Университет Джонса Хопкинса)
                    </p>
                </div><div>
                    <h4>Себастьян Нкомо Да Гама    </h4>
                    <p>(Всемирная Организация Здравоохранения - (ВОЗ)</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Бхава Поудьял    </h4>
                    <p>(Баку, Азербайджан)
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Атиф Рахман     </h4>
                    <p>(Университет Ливерпуля)
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Элисон Шафер    </h4>
                    <p>(World Vision International)
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Мариан Шильпероорд     </h4>
                    <p>(Управление Верховного комиссара по работе с сообщениями (УВКБ))
                    </p>
                </div>
    
                <div>
                    <h4>Ютаро Сетойя    </h4>
                    <p>(Всемирная Организация Здравоохранения - (ВОЗ)</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Марит Сийбрандиж    </h4>
                    <p>(Амстердамский свободный университет)
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Ренато Соуза    </h4>
                    <p>(Университет Сан-Паулу)
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Витсе Тол    </h4>
                    <p>(Университет Джонса Хопкинса)
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Питер Вентефогель    </h4>
                    <p>(Управление Верховного комиссара по работе с сообщениями (УВКБ))
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Хелена Вердели    </h4>
                    <p>(Колумбийский университет)
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Инка Вайсбекер    </h4>
                    <p>(Международный медицинский корпус)
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Валери Висард    </h4>
                    <p>(Женева, Швейцария)
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Таги Ясами      </h4>
                    <p>(Всемирная Организация Здравоохранения - (ВОЗ))
    
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Билл Юл      </h4>
                    <p>(Королевский колледж Лондона)
    
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                    <h4>Дуг Затзик      </h4>
                    <p>(Университет штата Вашингтон)
    
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a  href="#startComand" id="moreStuff" class="more usable">
                <div class="more">
                    <p id="show-text">Посмотреть весь список</p><p id="hide-text" class="disable">Скрыть дополнительный список</p> 
                    <img id="all-blank" src="img/Arrow.svg" alt="">
                </div>
            </a>
            
        </div>
.comand-stuff {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
    backdrop-filter: blur(17px);
    span {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: max-content;
        color: #8764C1;
    }
    div {
        padding: 15px 30px 0 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #8764C1;
        h4 {
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 24px;
        }
        p {
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 300;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 20px;
            margin: 5px 0;
        }
    }
    .more-stuff {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: none !important;
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
        &.active {
            height: 2490px;
        }
    }
    a.more.usable {
        z-index: 20;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 7px 0;
        &.active {
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
            backdrop-filter: blur(17px);
            position: sticky;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    }
    .more {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        width: max-content;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: none;
        p {
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 23px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: position:sticky конфликтует с overflow:hidden у родителя

Comment: Братаааан, от души, спасибо!!!!